# spoj palindrome, why isn't this being accepted?

Tags: python

The next code runs fine on my computer and does exactly what the problem states so why isn't it accepted? it keeps telling me time limit exceeded but this runs in under half a second...
The problem is this:
Input

The first line contains integer t, the number of test cases. Integers K are given in the next t lines.
Output
For each K, output the smallest palindrome larger than K.
My code:

```
def Find_Smallest_Palindrome(Number):
Number = str(int(Number) + 1)
while Number != Number[::-1]:
    Number = str(int(Number) + 1)
return Number

def Get_User_Input():
    Number = input('')
    return Number
print('Input: ')
Cycles = int(input(''))
x = 0
Numbers = []
while x < Cycles:
    Number = int(input(''))
    Numbers.append(Number)
    x += 1
print()
print('Output: ')
for Number in Numbers:
    print(Find_Smallest_Palindrome(str(Number)))
```

Comment: will take forever -- do it on paper first. Write a large number, and see what you, as an human, do to get to the smaller palindrome larger than that number - then replicate what you do by pencil and paper inside a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the exact formulation of the problem, but I think it is too slow for more complicated examples. Consider for instance the input

```
Find_Smallest_Palindrome(9999999900000000)
```

This will take very long with your code. I think, they test the given methods with such examples.